# Babel and jinja2 with coffin extension

Tags: python, django, python-babel, coffin

I'm trying to translate a jinja2/coffin template with Babel using the command line tool. The issue is that the function babel_extract jams on the coffin tags like {% url %} or {% csrf_token %}.

First, to detect the problem, I have modify jinja.ext.babel_extract and added "print e" on exceptions while rendering.

```
try:
    node = environment.parse(source)
    tokens = list(environment.lex(environment.preprocess(source)))
except TemplateSyntaxError, e:
    # skip templates with syntax errors
    print e
    return
```

When I run the extract method with Babel, it print out this error:

```
Encountered unknown tag 'url'. Jinja was looking for the following tags: 'endblock'. The innermost block that needs to be closed is 'block'. extracting messages from templates/contact.html (encoding="utf-8")
```

Then I have edit my babel config to add the Coffin Library. I have also set my environements variables to add my django project to my python path and set the django settings module to my settings.py.

```
[python: src/**.py]

[jinja2: templates/**.html]
encoding = utf-8
extensions = coffin.template.Library

[extractors]
jinja2 = jinja2.ext:babel_extract
```

Now, when I run the extract method, this error happens:

`extracting messages from templates/brands.html (extensions="coffin.template.Library", encoding="utf-8")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pybabel", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('Babel==0.9.6', 'console_scripts', 'pybabel')()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Babel-0.9.6-py2.7.egg/babel/messages/frontend.py", line 1107, in main
    return CommandLineInterface().run(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Babel-0.9.6-py2.7.egg/babel/messages/frontend.py", line 651, in run
    return getattr(self, cmdname)(args[1:])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Babel-0.9.6-py2.7.egg/babel/messages/frontend.py", line 912, in extract
    for filename, lineno, message, comments in extracted:
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Babel-0.9.6-py2.7.egg/babel/messages/extract.py", line 171, in extract_from_dir
    strip_comment_tags):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Babel-0.9.6-py2.7.egg/babel/messages/extract.py", line 201, in extract_from_file
    strip_comment_tags))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Babel-0.9.6-py2.7.egg/babel/messages/extract.py", line 275, in extract
    for lineno, funcname, messages, comments in results:
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/jinja2/ext.py", line 588, in babel_extract
    auto_reload=False
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 279, in __init__
    self.extensions = load_extensions(self, extensions)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 76, in load_extensions
    result[extension.identifier] = extension(environment)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`

Comment: is Library supposed to be capitalized there?